# Reference list is indented in first line

Tags: bibliographies, errors, cross-referencing

so I manually did my bibliography/references page and I'm coming across a slight problem.

```
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{1}Azih, Chioma Austin-Mona. “Analysis of Factors Contributing to Poverty in the United States: \\ 
An Empirical Study.” Methodist University, n.d. https://doi.org/https://www.methodist.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/mr2017_ chioma.pdf.  


\bibitem{2} “Crime in the U.S.” FBI. FBI, July 15, 2010. https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/. 


\bibitem{5} Glen, Stephanie. “Correlation Coefficient: Simple Definition, Formula, Easy Steps.” Statistics \\ How To, July 1, 2021. https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/correlation-coefficient-formula/. 
\bibitem{6}“How Does U.S. Income Inequality Compare Worldwide?” Saint Louis Fed Eagle. Federal \\ Reserve Bank of St. Louis, December 9, 2021. https://www.stlouisfed.org/on-the-economy/2017/october/how-us-income-inequality-compare-worldwide. 
\bibitem{7}“Income Inequality – Gini Index.” Our World in Data. Accessed March 2, 2022. \\ https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/economic-inequality-gini-index?tab=chart&country=~USA. 
\bibitem{8}“An Introduction to Variance, Covariance & Correlation: Alchemer Blog.” Alchemer, March 26, \\ 2018. https://www.alchemer.com/resources/blog/variance-covariance-correlation
\bibitem{9}John N. Mitchell, The Philadelphia Tribune. “Breaking Poverty: Crime, Poverty Often Linked.” \\ WHYY. WHYY, September 18, 2018. https://whyy.org/articles/breaking-poverty-crime-poverty-often-linked/. 
\bibitem{10}Published by Statista Research Department, and Feb 28. “U.S. Poverty Rate by State 2020.” \\ Statista, February 28, 2022. https://www.statista.com/statistics/233093/us-poverty-rate-by-state/. 
\bibitem{11}“Spearman's Rank-Order Correlation.” Spearman's Rank-Order Correlation - A guide to when to \\ use it, what it does and what the assumptions are. Accessed March 3, 2022. https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-statistical-guide.php. 
\bibitem{12} Zach. “Why Is Standard Deviation Important? (Explanation + Examples).” Statology, August 4, \\ 2021. https://www.statology.org/why-is-standard-deviation-important. 
\bibitem{13} \par Zhu, Heting, and Ana Maria Santacreu. “How Does U.S. Income Inequality Compare \\ \parindent  Worldwide?” Saint Louis Fed Eagle. Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis, December 9, 2017. https://www.stlouisfed.org/on-the-economy/2017/october/how-us-income-inequality-compare-worldwide. 
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 1):

You get many errors from that input, the first of which is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.7 ...dist.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/mr2017_
                                                   chioma.pdf.
?
```

(with a different line number, of course). You also get others due to `&` that should be `\&`.

Load the `xurl` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{1}
  Azih, Chioma Austin-Mona. 
  “Analysis of Factors Contributing to Poverty in the United States: 
  An Empirical Study.” Methodist University, n.d. \\
  \url{https://doi.org/https://www.methodist.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/mr2017_ chioma.pdf}

\bibitem{2}
   “Crime in the U.S.” FBI. FBI, July 15, 2010. \\
   \url{https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/}

\bibitem{5}
  Glen, Stephanie.
  “Correlation Coefficient: Simple Definition, Formula, Easy Steps.”
  Statistics How To, July 1, 2021. \\
  \url{https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/correlation-coefficient-formula/}

\bibitem{6}
  “How Does U.S. Income Inequality Compare Worldwide?”
  Saint Louis Fed Eagle. Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis, December 9, 2021. \\
  \url{https://www.stlouisfed.org/on-the-economy/2017/october/how-us-income-inequality-compare-worldwide}

\bibitem{7}
  “Income Inequality – Gini Index.”
  Our World in Data. Accessed March 2, 2022. \\
  \url{https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/economic-inequality-gini-index?tab=chart&country=~USA}

\bibitem{8}
  “An Introduction to Variance, Covariance \& Correlation: Alchemer Blog.” 
  Alchemer, March 26, 2018. \\
  \url{https://www.alchemer.com/resources/blog/variance-covariance-correlation}

\bibitem{9}
  John N. Mitchell,
  The Philadelphia Tribune. “Breaking Poverty: Crime, Poverty Often Linked.” 
  WHYY. WHYY, September 18, 2018. \\
  \url{https://whyy.org/articles/breaking-poverty-crime-poverty-often-linked/}

\bibitem{10}
  Published by Statista Research Department, and Feb 28.
  “U.S. Poverty Rate by State 2020.”
  Statista, February 28, 2022. \\
  \url{https://www.statista.com/statistics/233093/us-poverty-rate-by-state/}

\bibitem{11}
  “Spearman's Rank-Order Correlation.”
  Spearman's Rank-Order Correlation - A guide to when to use it, what it does 
  and what the assumptions are. 
  Accessed March 3, 2022. \\
  \url{https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-statistical-guide.php}

\bibitem{12}
  Zach.
  “Why Is Standard Deviation Important? (Explanation + Examples).” 
  Statology, August 4, 2021. \\
  \url{https://www.statology.org/why-is-standard-deviation-important}

\bibitem{13}
  Zhu, Heting, and Ana Maria Santacreu.
  “How Does U.S. Income Inequality Compare Worldwide?” 
  Saint Louis Fed Eagle. Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis, December 9, 2017. \\
  \url{https://www.stlouisfed.org/on-the-economy/2017/october/how-us-income-inequality-compare-worldwide}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You may also try without `\\`.

[image]